# How to replace '&amp;' with just '&'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ampersand

I'm trying to write a json to csv - using Python 3.6 - and the json contains `&amp;`.

How can I write just plain ampersands (`&`) instead of `&amp;`?

I've tried `str.replace` using a variety of escapes, and also some regex, all to no avail. Those `&amp;` s just won't budge!

Comment: Sorry, the '&amp;' s have been replaced in the question with '&', which funnily enough, is what I'm trying to do!

Comment: What encoding do you use? And is it the same for all files?

Comment: Hi Geshode: I'm using utf-8 (only because it seems the most popular). Is this my problem?

Comment: So, the json contains the `&amp`? Or does the CSV?

Comment: Hi Geshode: Yes, unfortunately the json contains "&amp;".

Comment: Can you post your code? `str.replace` should work well for this, depending on how you are using it. Have you tried: `s.replace(r'''&amp;''', r'''&''')` ? On a side note, I recommend jupyter notebooks useful to speed up problem solving.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = 'text with &amp; and more &amp; other text'
>>> s.replace('&amp;', '&')
'text with & and more & other text'
```